# intercept the opengl calls and make multi-viewpoints and multi-viewports

Tags: opengl, graphic

I want to creates a layer between any other OpenGL-based application and the original OpenGL library. It seamlessly intercepts OpenGL calls made by the application, and renders and sends images to the display, or sends the OpenGL stream to the rendering cluster.

I have completed my `openg32.dll` to replace the original library, I don't know what to do next,

How to convert OpenGL calls to images and what are OpenGL stream?

For an accurate description. visit [the Opengl Wrapper](http://www.holografika.com/Software-and-system-compatibility/Software-system-and-compatibility.html)

Comment: So you've changed "openg32.dll", but don't know how some of the things work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost OpenGL is not a libarary. It's an API. The opengl32.dll you have on your system is a library that provides the API and acts as a anchoring point for the actual graphics driver to attach to the programs.

Next it's a terrible idea to intercept OpenGL calls and turn them into something different, like multiple viewports. It may work for the fixed function pipeline, but as soon as shaders get involved it will break the program you hooked into. OpenGL is designed as an API to draw things to the screen, it's not a scene graph. Programs expect that when they make OpenGL calls they will produce an image in a pixel buffer according to their drawing commands. Now if you hook into that process and wildly alter the outcome, any graphics algorithm that relies on the visual outcome of the previous rendering for the following steps *will* break. For example any form of *shadow mapping* will be broken by what you do.

Also things like multiple viewport hacks will likely not work if the program does things like frustum culling internally, before making the actual OpenGL calls. Again this is because OpenGL is a drawing API, not a scene graph.

In the end yes you can hook into OpenGL, but whatever you do, you must make sure that OpenGL calls as made by the application get executed according to the specification. There is a authorative OpenGL specification for a reason, namely that programs rely on it to have predictable results.

Comment: thank you for you answer! if I want to turn any OpenGL-based application into multiple viewports . How shall I do it?

Comment: @user3131976: If it's an application developed by you (as indicated by your question) by implementing it in the drawing code using glViewport/glScissor and doing a render pass for each viewport (see Cosine's answer). You can't do it reliably for foreign programs though, short of modifying their code. A few years ago (before there was programmable hardware) I developed a water ripple effect that was completely done on the GPU. Had something like your idea been applied to that program it would have broken miserably.

Comment: Could you tell me how does the HoloVizio Opengl Wrapper work in the website [Opengl Wrapper](http://www.holografika.com/Software-and-system-compatibility/Software-system-and-compatibility.html). Unfortunately I does the same work with them

Comment: @user3131976: The big difference here is, that the intercepted OpenGL calls are not modified. The application still renders its geometry unaltered to its regular framebuffer. The trick is, that the intercepted calls are replayed into a second (off-screen) framebuffer, with the modelview and projection matrix slightly altered. **But** if you read the description carefully it's been tested and supported for only a limited number of programs and libraries, which is a telltale sign, that they have to carefully craft their tool toward each application.

Comment: @user3131976: Another, more flexible solution for what they to (create a 3D effect after the rendering) uses the information from the depth buffer to implement a parallax mapping effect. This is a lot more robust and will work with a wider range of applications. However it will work not at all for renderers that perform screen space postprocessing effects or multipass rendering or deferred rendering (the result will look just flat then).

Comment: @user3131976: However from a professional point of view this kind of patched "do it in post" application of stereoscopy yields only very poor results. I'm did and do a lot of stereoscopy work and for stereoscopy to look convincing, but more importantly not give you a headache or give you simulator sickness the stereoscopy has to by integrated carefully into the rendering process. I've got experience with that and trust me, such kinds of interception 3D effect libraries are not worth their money, even if they're for free.

Comment: Could you provide some references about "replay into a second(off-screen) framebuffer"? website or any other if possible.

Comment: @perlinson: If you Google for "OpenGL call tracer" it will give you several links to tools (BuGLe, spyGLass, apitrace are open source, so you can look at how they do it) that create recordings of the OpenGL calls a program makes. If you replay those calls to an OpenGL, with the exact data passed to them you should get a recreation of the original rendering. Now instead of recording to a file you can as well make the OpenGL calls immediately (or once you've reached the point where the result would be shown), but targeting a different context (or you use the same context but a different window).

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL almost undoubtedly allows you to do the things you want to do without doing crazy modifications to it. Multi-viewpoints can be done by, in your render function, doing the following

```
glViewport(/*View 1 window coords*/0, 0, window_width, window_height / 2);

// Do all of your rendering for the first camera

glViewport(/*View 2 window coords*/0, window_height / 2, window_width, window_height);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

// Redo your modelview matrix for a different viewpoint here, then re-render it all.
```

It's as simple as rendering twice into two areas which you specify with glViewport. If you Google around you can get a more detailed tutorial. I highly do not recommend messing with OpenGL as a good deal if it is implemented by the graphics card, and you should really just use what you're given. Chances are if you're modifying it you're doing it wrong. It probably allows you to do it a FAR better way.

Good luck!

Comment: I made a mistake ,it's not my OpenGL-based application but any other OpenGl-based application, I have done the things that you say